# Error 405 when running ionic on emulator with -l -c

Tags: ionic-framework

When i am running my app into android emulator with -livereload or -consolelogs. I am getting "405 (Method not allowed )" error or when run app without any parameters the app working fine in emulator or real device. The API in on the amazon server

This is the error in console in device inspect

OPTIONS "My API URL" 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load "My API URL". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.56.1:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-in-login-when-running-ionic-on-emulator-with-l-c/40650?u=harishgadiya92

Comment: Hey @harish found any solution for issue?

Comment: @paril, It's related to CORS. Need some modification on backend services. Your backend service need to allow request from your client PORT

Comment: @paril, It's related to CORS. Need some modification on backend services. Your backend service need to allow request from your client PORT. Or you can try content-policy meta tag in HTML file

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a **CORS** issue.

Try to install [Ionic/Cordova Whitelist plugin](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist) by running:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already install cordova-plugin-whitelist. When i run the app with -l -c parameter. I get below error in console without doing anything

Refused to load the script 'http://192.168.56.1:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".